# Data going missing from only one database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, data-loss

I have a small application that all it does it create and delete'monitors' in my database. I know for a fact that the delete route is not causing this before I can turn off the node application and walk away and come back 1 day later and data will be missing. It is only happening for this single monitors database. I have 3 others on the MongoDB server and the other 3 have no data loss.

My code is pretty simple for this, I have a post route that runs the blow code as a middleware/controller then that is it. Just exits the route and waits for another.

```
exports.newPost = function(req, res, next) {
  let name = req.body.name;


  if (!name) return res.status(400).json({success: false, message: 'You must fill in all required fields.'});

  let newMonitor = { name };

  Monitor.create(newMonitor, (err, monitor) => {
    if (err) return res.status(500).json({success: false, message: 'Error saving new monitor.'});
    return res.status(200).json({success: true, message: 'Successfully saved new monitor.'});
  });
};
```

Now this saves a document to the mongo database and I can see that by using the `mongo` CLI tool. Below is the model that is being called in the above code.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

const monitorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    createdAt: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now } 
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Monitor', monitorSchema);
```

Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas on what might be happening? I'm stumped on this totally.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issue I has was related to the fact that I had an expires previously on my collection that was to keep the database small for testing. When I dropped the collection thinking it would clear it. It did not clear it, instead it left the expires still in there. So what I had to do was `db.monitors.dropIndex('createdAt_1')` and that fixed it I think. I will know tomorrow if it fixed it since the expires was for 12 hours.